# Detect enter key pressed from custom NSTextView completion list

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstextview

I'm trying to detect the enter key from a custom NSTextView (from a NSTextField completion list) but I can't get it to work.

My interface:

```
@interface PaddedTextView : NSTextView < NSTextViewDelegate >
```

I implement:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(NSTextView *)textView doCommandBySelector (SEL)commandSelector
    {
```

But it is never called.

The Completion list disappears when I press enter after selecting an option.

I have also implemented:

```
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event
```

and it will detect alpha numeric key events but not the enter key.

I also have implemented flagsChanged to capture the shift key and that works.

I am using a custom NSTextField, NSTextFieldCell and NSTextView.

When I select a completion entry and hit the enter key the value will be inserted into the NSTextField control but I want to perform an action when this happens and I can't detect it...

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. (Update: This doesn't work)

I added the following to my NSTextView implementation:

```
-(void) insertCompletion:(NSString *)word forPartialWordRange:(NSRange)charRange movement:(NSInteger)movement isFinal:(BOOL)flag {
    if(movement == NSReturnTextMovement){
        NSLog(@"Enter key pressed...");
    }
    [super insertCompletion:word forPartialWordRange:charRange movement:movement isFinal:flag];
}
```

Update: Actually this doesn't always work. This function is only called when a completion option is selected. If you type in the text field and hit enter I can't detect that key event, it only dismisses the completion list. Still looking for a real solution.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about the completion list implementation, However at least on a normal NSTextView, `insertNewline:(id)sender` will be invoked when enter key is pressed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think my issue is that I want to capture the enter key on the completions list not really the NSTextView itself. But I don't know what class that is. I call complete:nil and the list pops up. I think the TextView receives key events from this list but it handles the enter key on it's own.